# "Waiting for first node to connect..." while connecting Minikube to Sysdig

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, sysdig

I'm trying to connect my local Kubernetes `Minikube` cluster to Sysdig.

I've exported the `ACCESS_KEY` to the environment and copied the yams configuration files as requested by the Sysdig documentation:

I started Minikube and run the following commands:

```
kubectl create ns sysdig-agent
kubectl create secret generic sysdig-agent --from-literal=access-key=${ACCESS_KEY} -n sysdig-agent
kubectl apply -f sysdig/sysdig-agent-clusterrole.yaml -n sysdig-agent
kubectl create serviceaccount sysdig-agent -n sysdig-agent
kubectl create clusterrolebinding sysdig-agent --clusterrole=sysdig-agent --serviceaccount=sysdig-agent:sysdig-agent
kubectl apply -f sysdig/sysdig-agent-configmap.yaml -n sysdig-agent
kubectl apply -f sysdig/sysdig-agent-daemonset-v2.yaml -n sysdig-agent
```

Here are the outputs (seems ok):

```
  minikube v1.1.1 on darwin (amd64) 
  Creating virtualbox VM CPUs=2, Memory=8192MB, Disk=20000MB) ... 
  Configuring environment for Kubernetes v1.14.3 on Docker 18.09.6 
  Pulling images ... 
  Launching Kubernetes ...  
⌛  Verifying: apiserver proxy etcd scheduler controller dns 
  Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube"

namespace/sysdig-agent created secret/sysdig-agent created
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/sysdig-agent created
serviceaccount/sysdig-agent created
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/sysdig-agent created
configmap/sysdig-agent created daemonset.extensions/sysdig-agent
created persistentvolumeclaim/orientdb-pv-claim created
deployment.extensions/orientdbservice created
```

In the Sysdig Monitor panel, I still see the following:

[image]

Comment: And when you ask your new question, be sure to include actual log output from ... anything ... because there is no way the Internet can _guess_ what is wrong with your setup. Also the output of `kubectl get nodes` and `kubectl get --all-namespaces pods -o wide`

Comment: Also, could you provide your YAMLs (without sensitive data)?

Comment: In addition, please let me know what vm-driver are you using. Also have you tried on newer version? Currently Minikube is 1.2.0, Kubernetes 1.15 and docker 18.09.7